# Configure and install wordpress and apache or nginx to run multiple wordpress sites on one linode

Tags: linux, wordpress, apache, docker, docker-compose

I'm new to this forum, I'm from Santiago de Chile, it's a pleasure
I am interested in being able to use worpress using docker.
I would like to know how to configure a docker-compose file that allows me to install worpress php, mysql and apache and create a "virtual host" configuration by going to the selected website in wordpress
Thanks for your help.

Excuse my english, and thank you very much to whoever gives me help

Comment: Mostly, we don't ask solutions here but issues while we deploy a solution. So you may try to deploy your own compose file and then ask questions if you meet some.

Comment: Have you tried https://linode.com/docs/quick-answers/linux/wordpress-with-docker-compose/ ?